# Is there a way to use postfix notation to call a function in Rust without defining a new trait?

Tags: methods, rust, traits

Perhaps my terminology is wrong, but is there a way to use postfix notation to call a function in Rust without defining a new trait?  Basically, I have a vector of `&str` and I'd like to convert them into a string with the notation `myvec.as_string()`.  Currently, I can do this with the code

```
trait Foo {                
    fn as_string(&self) -> String;
}   

impl Foo for Vec<&str> {  
    fn as_string(&self) -> String {
        let mut mystr = self
            .iter()
            .fold(String::new(),|sum,s| format!("{}{}:", sum, s));
        mystr.pop();
        mystr
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_vec = vec!["bar", "buz", "baz"];
    use crate::Foo;       
    println!("{}", my_vec.as_string());
}
```

That said, in order to make this work, I needed to define a trait called `Foo` that I don't really care about and the trait needed to be opened with `use crate::Foo` prior to the call to `as_string`.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?  And, to be clear, I'd like to avoid the notation `as_string(myvec)` if possible because the postfix notation has been nice for chaining together commands.

Comment: where by "postfix notation" you mean "define and call a method"? You can do that without traits, no?

Comment: Ah, but not for external types, I see.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Precisely.  I tried just `impl Vec <&str>`, but receive the compilation error `impl for type defined outside of crate`.  As such, to be clear, this is for types that I did not define, such as `Vec <&str>` above.

Comment: Just going to add that your example can already be accomplished using a [pre-existing method](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=77ee34ffb97bab56502ed85bd3477635) who's definition can be found [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceConcatExt.html#tymethod.join)

Comment: What wrong with defining a trait ?

Comment: It was just more verbose than I'd like for something that I thought would be more simple.  That said, it's fine and I appreciate the help.  Really, @OptimisticPeach has a better way to accomplish this, thanks for that, but I learned something in this process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common pattern!

If you want to add methods to a type that is defined in another crate, the official way to do so is it define a trait and implement it for that type. If the type is from another crate then *this is the **only** way to do it*.

A ubiquitous example of this is the crate [`itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/) which uses a trait to add useful methods to every existing implementation of `std::iter::Iterator`.

`Itertools` works just as you describe. There is a trait which declares a number of methods:

```
pub trait Itertools : Iterator {
    fn interleave<J>(self, other: J) -> Interleave<Self, J::IntoIter>
        where J: IntoIterator<Item = Self::Item>,
              Self: Sized
    {
        interleave(self, other)
    }

    // etc...
}
```

It is defined for all `Iterator`s:

```
impl<T: ?Sized> Itertools for T where T: Iterator { }
```

And, whenever you want to use these extra methods, you import it:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

let it = (1..7).interleave(vec![-1, -2]);
itertools::assert_equal(it, vec![1, -1, 2, -2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a macro such as [the following provided by Lucretiel](https://github.com/Lucretiel/nom-supreme/blob/f5cc5568c60a853e869c784f8a313fb5c6151391/src/lib.rs)...

```
macro_rules! express {
        ($thing:ident $( . $method:ident ( $($args:tt)* ) )*) => {{
            let mut thing = $thing;
            $( thing.$method($($args)*); )*
            thing
        }};
    }
```

Example usage...

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![];
    let b = express!(a.push(1).push(2).push(34));
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/50125650e278dc8ddcab2c00a947aef3)